# User input to break while loop?

Tags: python-3.x

Alright so I need to write code so that basically acts as a cashier. To do this the cashier must ask the user what they want, how much of it they want, and then ask them if they want something else until they're finished with their order.

I've set the values for any variables that I will use.

```
while (order != 'done' or 'Done'): #goal: repeat "can I take your order"
    order == input("Can I take your Order? (Enter food item or 'done' to complete order)  ")
    if (order == 'burger' or 'Burger'): 
        a = float(input("How many would you like?  "))
        break
```

When I do something like the above code my program will break after input of 'burger'.

```
while (order != 'done' or 'Done'): #goal: repeat "can I take your order"
    order == input("Can I take your Order? (Enter food item or 'done' to complete order)  ")
    if (order == 'burger' or 'Burger'): 
        a = float(input("How many would you like?  "))

    elif (order == 'cheeseburger' or 'Cheeseburger'):
        b = float(input("How many would you like?  "))
        break
    elif (order == 'fries' or 'Fries'):
        c = float(input("How many would you like?  "))
        break
    elif (order== 'done' or 'Done'):
        break
```

When I remove break from just when input is supposed to be 'burger' then no matter the input in will keep asking for my order.

> 1. Can I take your Order? (Enter food item or 'done' to complete order)  burger
> 2. How many would you like?  3
> 3. Can I take your Order? (Enter food item or 'done' to complete order)  done
> 4. How many would you like?  0
> 5. Can I take your Order? (Enter food item or 'done' to complete order)  chocolate
> 6. How many would you like?  0
> 7. Can I take your Order? (Enter food item or 'done' to complete order)  fries
> 8. How many would you like?  2
>      Can I take your Order? (Enter food item or 'done' to complete order)

I don't know what's wrong with my code. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You're missing a `break`...

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not assigning "order", you are just comparing it. Difference between = and ==

```
order = input("Can I take your Order? (Enter food item or 'done' to complete order)  ")
```

Plus

```
while (order.lower() != 'done'):
```

because  **order != 'done' or order != 'Done'** will always result in **True**

Plus

```
order != 'burger' or 'Burger'
```

will result in **Burger** if order is 'burger' other wise it will result in 'Burger'

```
>>> order = raw_input()
burger
>>> order == 'burger' or 'Burger'
True
>>> order = raw_input()
done
>>> order == 'burger' or 'Burger'
'Burger'
```

So, somehow your first **if** is always true

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your choice of loop expressions. In short, `or` doesn't work the way you think it does. I'll focus on the while loop, but you make the same mistake in the `if` statement.

Consider this code:

```
while (order != 'done' or 'Done')
```

This is the same as:

```
while ((order != 'done') or ('Done')):
```

... which is roughly the same as

```
while ((order != 'done') or ('Done' != "")):
```

In other words, the statement will aways be true because `'Done'` is considered to be "[truthy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)".

Solution: write it like this:

```
while (order != 'done' and order != "Done"):
```

... or even better, to catch all cases:

```
while (order.lower() != "done"):
```

Comment: Hey thanks! We haven't gone over cases in my class but this assignment needed lower or upper for the input. This makes sense to me.